# does fixedRowCount exist in react-window?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

There was a prop **fixedRowCount** available in the react-virtualized ([MultiGrid component](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/MultiGrid.md)) repo, does it exist in the rewrite of virtualized, now called react-window?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it to see?

Comment: I mean have you checked to see if it exists?

Comment: It doesn't, that's why I am asking if it exists or maybe it was renamed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example will do the thing, change the flex direction to column. basically, add one row grid on top and then the table rows in another grid

https://codesandbox.io/s/2jvl09przn